# what scripting language will work on my girlfriends work computer?

Tags: windows-7

someone keeps moving folders around on my girlfriends workplace network, breaking all her shortcuts to useful places on the labyrinthine network. The IT department is like 'meh', her colleagues that keep ruining the order of things are like 'u say wha?', so my idea is to write some code that will let her relink everything in an efficient manner every time someone messes it up.
What scripting language should i use?
the constraints are:

*default win7 installation
*not allowed to install programs
*no help expected from IT department
*ease of use for a non tech person
*i will never know more than already stated about the running environment

thanks!

Answer (score 3):

[Windows Powershell](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2009/10/27/windows-management-framework-is-here.aspx) is installed by default on Windows 7

Comment: Oh good call, and you can write cmdlets in C# too (provided you can copy DLLs onto the filesystem)..  I think you need admin rights to allow unsigned code to run on Powershell though, that might cause issues..

Answer (score 1):

I would say your choices are:

`Batch:` (*.BAT, *.CMD)

`Windows Scripting Host:` (WScript.exe, CScript.exe)

Stuff like .NET will just compile to an `EXE` which could be blocked.  Python and Perl probably aren't installed by default.

In case you're interested, here's how to create a shortcut using Windows Scripting Host:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fywyxt64

Comment: batch wont work, there's no command for shortcuts, so i need something more powerful, i just don't know which ones work out of the box.

Comment: So basically your script would find things on a network drive, then create shortcuts to things she cares about?

Comment: it would look at her existing shortcuts, see if they work, if not prompt her to correct one link in on a broken branch, automatically fix all other links on the same branch, repeat.

Answer (score 1):

Windows PowerShell is installed by default, and there are even some people who have had to automate making shortcuts before.  There are two scripts on our Tools page you should check out:

http://tools.start-automating.com/Add-Favorite/ - Adds shortcut items to the favorites folder.

http://tools.start-automating.com/Resolve-ShortcutFile - Resolves Existing shortcut files (so you can determine if the link is broken).

Hope this Helps